# Subfloat alignment: graphics and table on the same line

Tags: tables, graphics, subfloats

I'm trying to align an image and a table whithin the same figure, however, some alignment issues arise.

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb] 
  \centering 
  \begin{tabular}{l}
  \subfloat[]{
   \includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{Figures/goldmine} \label{fig:goldmineGraphic}}  
    \subfloat[]{
      %\input{Figures/Tikz/goldMineState.tex}\label{fig:goldMineState}}  
      \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Object & Attributes \\
    \midrule
    $miner1$ & $x=0,y=1$ \\
    $miner2$ & $x=1,y=3$ \\
    $miner3$ & $x=4,y=3$ \\
    $gold1$ & $x=1,y=0$ \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\vdots$} \\
    $gold6$ & $x=4,y=2$ \\
    $wall1$ & $x=1,y=1,pos=S$ \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\vdots$}\\
    $wall24$ & $x=4,y=4,pos=E$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
  \end{tabular}
 \caption{AA}
 \label{fig:goldmine}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: code result]

What I actually wanted is something like this, with the two subfloats (the graphic and the table) aligned horizontally (not overstepping each other):

[image]

Any idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could choose `adjustbox` package as one of the options.  The package provides `\adjustbox` command with lot of options.  Here is the amended code for your requirement.

**Note:** I have added `\usepackage{adjustbox}` and `\adjustbox{raise=-5pc}` in this code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb] 
  \centering 
  \begin{tabular}{l}
  \subfloat[]{\adjustbox{raise=-5pc}{\includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{Figures/goldmine} \label{fig:goldmineGraphic}}}
    \subfloat[]{
      %\input{Figures/Tikz/goldMineState.tex}\label{fig:goldMineState}}  
      \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Object & Attributes \\
    \midrule
    $miner1$ & $x=0,y=1$ \\
    $miner2$ & $x=1,y=3$ \\
    $miner3$ & $x=4,y=3$ \\
    $gold1$ & $x=1,y=0$ \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\vdots$} \\
    $gold6$ & $x=4,y=2$ \\
    $wall1$ & $x=1,y=1,pos=S$ \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\vdots$}\\
    $wall24$ & $x=4,y=4,pos=E$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
  \end{tabular}
 \caption{AA}
 \label{fig:goldmine}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]